# Wrong side information in WM_SIZING for window with a very small height

Tags: delphi, winapi, window

1. I create a captionless window.
2. I resize it manually (or programmatically) so that its height is 30 pixels or less.
3. When I then grab the bottom border to resize it vertically, it behaves as
   if I were dragging the top border. Indeed when debugging the program, the WM_SIZING parameter contains WMSZ_TOP instead of WMSZ_BOTTOM.

My program is written in Delphi, basically the problem is reproducible with a main form with the following FormCreate:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  var oldStyle : LongInt;
  var newStyle : LongInt;

begin
  //  Adapt windows style.

  oldStyle := WINDOWS.GetWindowLong (
                          handle,
                          GWL_STYLE);

  newStyle := oldStyle              and
              (not WS_CAPTION)      and
              (not WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);

  WINDOWS.SetWindowLong(
              handle,
              GWL_STYLE,
              newStyle);

  //  SetWindowPos with SWP_FRAMECHANGED needs to be called at that point
  //  in order for the style change to be taken immediately into account.

  WINDOWS.SetWindowPos(
              handle,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              SWP_NOZORDER     or
              SWP_NOMOVE       or
              SWP_NOSIZE       or
              SWP_FRAMECHANGED or
              SWP_NOACTIVATE);
end;
```

Comment: a side note, better set the window styles via `CreateParams`.

Comment: Hi, your suggestion is welcome. BUT, for some reason, if I use CreateParams as follows, my form comes up with a caption:

  inherited CreateParams(
                params);

  with params do style := style and (not WS_CAPTION) and (not WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me with the OS. Under the conditions of your test case, hit test handling is wrong, default window procedure returns `HTTOP` when it should return `HTBOTTOM`. You can override hit test handling for a workaround:

```
procedure TForm1.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Message.Result = HTTOP) and
      (Message.Pos.Y > Top + Height - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME)) then
    Message.Result := HTBOTTOM;
end;
```

Comment: @Emmanuel - You're welcome. I haven't tested but I wouldn't be surprised if you need to employ similar override for left-right and/or corner sizing. You might need to extend this but you get the idea.

Answer (score 5):

Well done, thanks. I confirm that it is an OS bug and nothing related to delphi (I was able to reproduce the problem with a simple window created using the WINDOWS API).

I now ended up with:

```
procedure TForm2.WMNcHitTest(
                     var msg : TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  inherited;

  case msg.result of

      HTTOP:
        begin
          if msg.pos.y > top + height div 2 then
              msg.result := HTBOTTOM;
        end;

      HTTOPRIGHT:
        begin
          if msg.pos.y > top + height div 2 then
              msg.result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
        end;

      HTTOPLEFT:
        begin
          if msg.pos.y > top + height div 2 then
              msg.result := HTBOTTOMLEFT;
        end;

  end;
end;
```